# Passing sequelize model instance to a service is not working in express.js

Tags: node.js, class, express, inheritance, sequelize.js

I want to access findById function of CRUDService in ItemService. I'm getting response from readAll function but not getting from findById. I think dao object what I'm passing to CRUDService from ItemService through constructor is not working. I'm new in node js and express js. Could you help me please.

This is Crud Service

```
class CRUDService{

  constructor(dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  readAll = () => {
    const rows = dao.findAll();
    return rows;
  };

  findById = (rowId) => {
    const row = dao.findByPk(rowId);
    return row;
  };
}

module.exports = CRUDService
```

This is Item Service

```
const CRUDService = require('../common/crud.service.js');
const ItemDAO = require('./item.dao.js');

class ItemService extends CRUDService{

  constructor() {
    const dao = new ItemDAO();
    super(ItemDAO);
  }

  readAll = () => {
    const rows = ItemDAO.findAll();
    return rows;
  };
}

module.exports = ItemService
```

This is DAO

```
const {Sequelize, Model} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database');

class ItemDAO extends Model {}

ItemDAO.init(
{
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1
  },
  name_en: Sequelize.STRING,
  name_local: Sequelize.STRING,
  created_at: Sequelize.TIME,
  created_by: Sequelize.STRING,
  is_deleted: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
  },
  { 
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Item',
    schema: 'cat',
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'item'
  }
);

module.exports = ItemDAO;
```

Comment: could you please describe clear ? i didn't get your point .

Comment: I want to pass ItemDao instance to CrudService from ItemService and use it in CrudService. @Vyas Arpit

Comment: Finally found the it. Problem wasn't about sequlize but arrow function scope and async/await. Below code snippet works fine for me.
    `findById = async function(rowId) {
        const row = await this.dao.findByPk(rowId);
        return row;
    };`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the instance of your `ItemDAO` to the super constructor.

```
const CRUDService = require('../common/crud.service.js');
const ItemDAO = require('./item.dao.js');
class ItemService extends CRUDService{

  constructor() {
    super(new ItemDAO()); // ---> here
  }

  readAll = () => {
    const rows = this.readAll();
    return rows;
  };
}

module.exports = ItemService
```

Also need to modify your service.

```
class CRUDService{

  constructor(dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  readAll = () => this.dao.findAll().then(rows => rows);

  findById = (rowId) => this.dao.findByPk(rowId).then(row => row);
}
```

Also remember those methods return promises so better to use `.then()` or use `async/await`.

Comment: Would you pleas drop the stack if you are getting any error?

Comment: Problem was about bothg arrow function scope and async/await. @Sujeet Agrahari